# Don't overlap Pins in com.appyvet.rangebar.RangeBar

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar) library to create Double RangeBar in android. Now in this rangebar i want that if left pin overlaps the right pin it must return to its previous position instead of overlapping and same for right pin. This is same as used in flipkart to filter price ranges.(Flipkart uses Range bar like this). I want to implement same property like that. How can i implement this property. Please help me..
Thanks in advance.
This is my Activity and xml

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.range_bar);
    min = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.min);
    sign_rupees = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_rupees);
    sign_rupees2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_rupees2);
    selected_min = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_min);
    selected_max = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_max);

    rangeBar = (RangeBar)findViewById(R.id.rangebar3);
    rangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex, int rightPinIndex, String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {

    int diff = rightPinIndex-leftPinIndex;

    if (diff == 0){
            rangeBar.setRangePinsByIndices(leftPinIndex-1,rightPinIndex+1);
            rangeBar.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        rangeBar.setEnabled(true);
        if (leftPinIndex == 0){
            min.setText("Min");
            min.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sign_rupees.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            selected_min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            min.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sign_rupees.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selected_min.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selected_min.setText(String.valueOf(leftPinIndex*500));
        }


        if (rightPinIndex == 6){
            selected_max.setText("2500+");
        }else{
            selected_max.setText(String.valueOf(rightPinIndex*500));
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rangebar1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <com.appyvet.rangebar.RangeBar
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rangebar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:tickStart="0"
        custom:tickInterval="1"
        custom:tickEnd="6"
        custom:pinRadius="20dp"
        custom:pinMinFont="5sp"
        custom:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
        custom:selectorSize="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rangebar1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Min Price"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Min"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/min_price"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_rupees"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rupees_symbol"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/min_price"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_min"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="250"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/min_price"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sign_rupees"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rangebar1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/max_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Max Price"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/max_price"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_rupees2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rupees_symbol"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_max"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2500+"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Found a good way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library , but looking at their code what you can try is :

```
@Override
public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex, int rightPinIndex, String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {

    int diff = rightPinIndex-leftPinIndex;

    if (diff == 0){
            rangeBar.setRangePinsByIndices(leftPinIndex-1,rightPinIndex+1);
            rangeBar.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        rangeBar.setEnabled(true);
        if (leftPinIndex == 0){
            min.setText("Min");
            min.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sign_rupees.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            selected_min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            min.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sign_rupees.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selected_min.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selected_min.setText(String.valueOf(leftPinIndex*500));
        }


        if (rightPinIndex == 6){
            selected_max.setText("2500+");
        }else{
            selected_max.setText(String.valueOf(rightPinIndex*500));
        }
    }

        if(rightPinIndex <= leftPinIndex) { 
            rangebar.setRangePinsByIndices(leftIntIndex-5, rightIntIndex+5); // This +-5 value can be anything
        }
}
```